# failing to play the whole video using cv2

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to play a video using cv2 but it's only showing one frame and the video disappears

```
import cv2
```

img_file = 'car image.jpg'
video = cv2.VideoCapture('Tesla Dashcam AccidentTrim.mp4')

while True:

```
(read_successful, frame) = video.read()

if read_successful:
    grayscaled_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else:
    break
```

classifier_file = 'car_detector.xml'

#Display the image with the faces spotted
cv2.imshow('Newton Caffrey Face Detector', grayscaled_frame)

#Don't Autoclose here (wait here in the code and listen for a key press)
cv2.waitKey(1)

Comment: First of all, it is recommended that the video name should not have spaces and the path to the video is read properly, also increase the time in the ```cv2.waitKey()```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code for displaying the video using cv2. It will keep displaying frames untill video ends. hope this will work for you, peace!

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Video.mp4")

width = 400
height = 300
num = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
     frame = cv2.resize (frame, (width, height))
     cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
         break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```